# Transparent PyQT5 window does not show over fullscreened application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently trying to make an overlay for games using a transparent PyQT5 window. My current code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop, QtCore.QSize(round(screeninfo.get_monitors()[0].width/3), round(screeninfo.get_monitors()[0].height/5)), QtWidgets.qApp.desktop().availableGeometry()))
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.show()
```

Except it doesn't show over fullscreened applications (like games). Is there an attribute I can set that can enable it to show on top of fullscreened applications as well?

Comment: A fullscreen window is by its nature a top level and stacked on top of everything else. If you want to show a window *above* that, you have at least to ensure that the window is `raise_()` when it loses focus. But that is not guaranteed, as it completely depends on the window manager. Simply put: you might not be able to do it.

Comment: raise_() doesn't seem to work. You might be right, but do you have an suggestion for another module that might be able to do what I'm trying to do? Or is it just impossible overall in the windows os